# Enabling SecureBoot

Tags: grub-efi, secure-boot

I want to enable Secure Boot on my asus ux303ln laptop to enhance security.
This means I do not want to use "shim" bootloader to be able to dual-boot into Windows, and I do want to have my own generated master key.
I am using Ubuntu 15.10, but I do not think it is important (at least, I had the same problem on 15.04).

I tried to follow the instructions on [SecurityTeam/SecureBoot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot) manual but have not succeeded - BIOS says that signature validating failed.

In more detail, steps I have done:

1. Enabled Secure boot in BIOS and deleted all factory keys (this put SecureBoot into "Setup" mode);
2. Followed the instructions from part [Bootloader signed with Canonical key](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot#Bootloader_signed_with_Canonical_key) of the manual, this means:

   a) Installed all suggested packages, including signed versions of grub and linux-image

   b) `grub-install --uefi-secure-boot`;

   c) Downloaded keys and run `sb-setup enroll canonical`;

   d) Checked one more time `vmlinuz` and `grubx64.efi` signatures using `sbverify`;
3. In BIOS I set another boot option to boot specifically from file `grubx64.efi`, but the signature error occurs on boot anyway.

So, the question is: why this happens, and how to solve this?

I am happy to provide any other specific details.

Comment: I use Ubuntu on many ASUS laptops with secure boot enabled and have no problems at all. I do not need to do anything special.

Comment: I also have a feeling that once I installed Ubuntu erasing Windows 8, without turning off Secure Boot, and could not boot after the first kernel update. But I am not sure on this matter (maybe it had been in the setup mode - with erased keys), and I do not want to reinstall current system.

Comment: Under boot options in BIOS, is Launch CSM enabled? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: Are you sure it broke after kernel-update, not distribution-upgrade? Can you boot to the previous kernel?

Comment: CSM disabled. About kernel/distribution : please, do not assume it was working, I am not sure about configuration at that time. I can tell everything about my current configuration though. I hoped some other asus users could check if SecureBoot works/enabled properly on their laptops.

Comment: You never had to do this mess... Canonical already supports Microsoft's key for Secure Boot using the "shim" bootloader. Now it has become very complicated and hard to solve. @Pilot6 is right. Your question is quite clear, but it's got REAL complicated.

Comment: If it was easy, I would not ask, would I? And the instruction on the wiki page was pretty clear, besides the problem that it did not work for me in the end :) "shim" bootloader is just a workaround for having two operating systems, it does not prevent you from loading not signed kernel, so there is no point in using it if I have erased Windows.